# ¿Porque no puedo pasar un *p a una funcion?

Tags: c++, punteros, memoria

Estoy revisando un poco de punteros y direcciones de memoria con funciones y me confunde un poco su uso

Si mi función `hallarMax(int*,int)` va a recibir un puntero (`int*`), ¿Por qué no puedo pasar un  `*p` y sólo debo pasar un `&p`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int hallarMax(int*,int);

int main()
{

    int arreglo[]= {4,6,10,4,9};

    int *p = arreglo;

    cout<<hallarMax(*p,5);//No me acepta enviar un *p y sólo debo enviar p

    return 0;
}

int hallarMax(int *p,int tam)
{
    int maximo = *p;
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        if(*(p+i)>maximo)
            maximo = *(p+i);
    }
    return maximo;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Si mi función `hallarMax(int*,int)` va a recibir un puntero (`int*`), ¿Por qué no puedo pasar un `*p` y sólo debo pasar un `&p`?

Vaya lío de conceptos tienes. Intentaré aclararlos:

- ¿Qué es `p`?

  `p` es un puntero a entero (`int*`), tal y como se ve en su declaración:

  ```
     int *p = arreglo;
  // ^^^^^ <--- Puntero a entero (int *).
  ```
- ¿Qué es `*p`?

  Dado que `p` es un puntero a entero (`int*`), el contenido de `p` (es decir `*p`) será un entero (`int`).
- ¿Qué es `&p`?

  Dado que `p` es un puntero a entero (`int*`), la dirección de `p` (es decir `&p`) será un puntero a un puntero a entero (`int**`).

Así que si tu función `hallarMax(int*,int)` va a recibir un puntero (`int*`) no puedes pasarle un entero (`*p`) ni un puntero a puntero (`&p`).

Answer (score 6):

> > ¿Porque no puedo pasar un *p a una funcion?

¡Porque es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)! Esto quiere decir que el programa puede que funcione o puede que no funcione o puede que nunca funcione, puede pasar cualquiera cosa...

Esto puede conducir a un [fallo de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso) (intentar acceder a una dirección de memoria que al programa no le pertenece).

**Ejemplo del error:**

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(int*);

int main()
{

    int arreglo[]= {4,6,10,4,9};

    int *p = arreglo;
    foo((int*)*p);//--> Se hace el casting para engañar al compilador de C++.


    return 0;
}

void foo(int * pe)
{
     *pe = 10; //--> aquí ocurre un fallo de segmentación
}
```

Cuando se ejecute la función `foo`, le estarías pasando al puntero `pe` el primer elemento (un entero) del *array*, sin embargo, ese *elemento* también es una dirección de memoria, por ende, el puntero estaría guardando la dirección `0x04`.

Cuando esta sentencia se ejecute:

```c
*pe = 10;
```

Ocurrirá un fallo de segmentación si la dirección `0x04` está siendo ocupada por otro proceso, ya que estarías intentando escribir el número `10` en una dirección que al programa no le pertenece. Esto ocasiona que el proceso actual termine su ejecución.

En cambio, si pasaras la dirección de memoria del primer elemento al parámetro `pe`, ahí sería distinto, porque es una dirección que fue asignada al proceso actual y por ende, es accesible:

```c
int arreglo[]= {4,6,10,4,9};
int *p = arreglo;
foo(p);//--> Esto es lo ideal, ya que pasamos la dirección del primer elemento y así podemos modificar el contenido del array durante la ejecución de la función foo.
```

> > ¿Por qué no puedo pasar un  *p?

No puedes pasar `*p` porque el parámetro espera la dirección de una variable de tipo `int` y no un *entero*.

> > ¿Sólo debo pasar un &p?

No, si haces eso, estarías pasando la dirección de memoria del puntero pero el parámetro solo espera la dirección de una variable de tipo `int` y no la de un puntero. En ese caso el parámetro de la función debería ser declarado como un [puntero doble](https://www.uv.es/eees/archivo/PON-C-13.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Porque tu función espera una dirección de memoria y cuando haces `*p` estas enviando el valor del puntero, pero cuando haces `&p` envías la dirección de memoria del puntero.

Puedes leer un poco mas sobre eso aquí: [Punteros.pdf](https://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/cursos/prog3/utils/Punteros.pdf)